How to make a separate leaf for missing values in sklearn decision trees
I want to build a decision tree model using explanatory variables which have meaningful missing values. For example, one of my variables is the percentage change in a variable between two dates. Naturally when the denominator is equal to zero then variable cannot be computed and is set to NaN.
Now, I would like to build a decision tree which creates a leaf for all the missing values from the root node, and uses the remaining data to fit a regular tree. The final tree should be something like this:
if x == NaN:
  y = 0.2
elif x < 5:
  y = 0.8
else:
  y = 0.5

Is there a way to do this in Scikit learn?
I know I can manually adjust the results of the predict method, but it seems to be like such a functionality should be already incorporated into the package.
